# Dúvida sobre como transformar um objeto de uma gridView em não clicável

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview, grid

Olá,

Tenho uma gridView que construi com um adapter que herda de BaseAdapter.
Quero que na minha activity, quando clicar em um item(tenho 16 no total na minha), faça com que outros itens se tornem clicáveis e vice e versa.

Alguem sabe uma maneira de se fazer isso???

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português @FernandoSchelb . Podias adicionar o código relevante à tua pergunta? não digo postar o código completo de todos os 16 items, mas o necessário para se poder ver e testar isto como por exemplo pelo menos 3

Comment: Poste o código do seu *adapter*

Answer (score 0):

A view usada no GridView é clicável se você a definir, porem pode ser controlado esses atributos em sua classe Adapter que estende de BaseAdapter.

Ainda é possível definir os eventos que serão usados em sua view.

Observe o exemplo:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html

Lembre de sempre verificar a documentação, existe muitas informações uteis por lá.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

Comment: desculpe, mas ainda sou iniciante.... já tinha visto as duas documentações que me enviou, mas ainda não resolvi meu problema. Poderia colocar um exemplo de adapter mudando a view para não clicável? Como recupero essa view.

Comment: Observe esse post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894815/androidclickable-true-means-that-its-not-clickable